# How can I convert the KITTI dataset into a bag file?

Tags: opencv, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to convert the monocular KITTI image dataset and poses into a bag file to test computer vision algorithms. I have done some research, however, I have not found any reliable solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357823/how-can-i-convert-the-kitti-dataset-into-a-bag-file?/) by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[kitti2bag](https://github.com/tomas789/kitti2bag) ROS Package will help you.

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) on 2020-07-26**:
Thanks It worked!

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2020-07-27**:
Please mark the answer as correct :)