# How to convert the kittti dataset into ros2 bags?

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, rosbag, ros-humble

How to convert the [kitti dataset](https://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/index.php) into ros2 bags, or is possible to download it already converted?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/umtclskn/ros2_kitti_publishers looks to publish topics live using the native kitti format, you would have to ros2 bag record the published topics to get it into bags.

It hasn't been updated in a few years so maybe needs some fixes to work with newer ros2 versions- but there are some updates in forks as seen in https://github.com/umtclskn/ros2_kitti_publishers/network - if you run into issues you could browse those and see if they have already been addressed.

If none of that works maybe there is route where the data is first [converted into ros1 bags](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/96610/how-can-i-convert-the-kitti-dataset-into-a-bag-file), then [convert those to ros2 bags](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/102071/convert-use-rosbag1-with-ros2-on-ubuntu-22-04).

Answer (score 0):

So, I have created a one for this purpose: [kitti_to_ros2bag](https://github.com/Chris7462/kitti_to_ros2bag).
Enjoy.